# IE11 Caching issue using MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, caching

I got a browser page caching issue specifically with IE 11, the **SomePage** page is always loaded from browser cache. The same page work's perfectly in Edge, Chrome and FF.

The page is called from a JS function as below:

```
$.ajaxJsonAntiForgery({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SomeAPI", "cntrl"))',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { model: model },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                window.location = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SomePage", "cntrl"))';
        ...
```

I have tried following approached:

1. Appending some random number with the URL. - Didn't work
2. Added following code in action method : - Didn't work

   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
   Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
   Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
   Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.Zero);
   Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);

and in Fiddler I can see following headers:

[image: Fiddler]

3. Adding OutputCache attributes on SomePage action method. - Didn't work

   [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*", Location =     System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None)]

[image: Fiddler]

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

[image]

Please advice, what else should be in this page header, which will instruct the browser - that it should not cache this page?

Answer (score 1):

You can globally turn caching off. Or by decorating the  action in the controller

```cs
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    Public ActionResult SomeApi(string param){
    ...
    }
```

> In ASP.NET MVC, you can use the OutputCacheAttribute attribute to mark
>   action methods whose output you want to cache. If you mark a
>   controller with the OutputCacheAttribute attribute, the output of all
>   action methods in the controller will be cached [or not cached depending on the attribute values].
>   [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx#Syntax)

Also of note: if your page actually has not changed, ASP.NET is smart enough to use a cached page for speed.

---

Updating after troubleshooting steps above tried. 
What about setting up your Ajax before the call.

```cs
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});
```

Comment: Actually I had tried that, however, that didn't work too. Tx

Comment: Sounds like an issue not related to your project solution. Have you tried it on another machine?

Comment: How about using $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});

Comment: As per the official documentation. _Set default values for future Ajax requests. **Its use is not recommended.**_

Comment: Does it correct the issue? Because if official documentation from Microsoft about asp.net is not working with ie11 perhaps it is just IE11 or another configuration you have in the project. - sorry I am not sure what else to try other than testing on another machine.

Comment: Yeah it works. I added that in .cshtml file and commented all code in controller. However, I am not sure what other issues it will open up. And yes, the issue can be very well replicated on other machines. The classic "it works on my machine" is also not true :). As I can replicate that on my machine too.

Comment: For this I would open a ticket with Microsoft for mvc5 as it is still supported. As well I would make sure you are using asp.net jquery Ajax lib namespace https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax